# How to remove the first nav menu divider

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, separator

I can't seem to remove the first nav menu separator (small-black-heart-md.png) from the navigation. All the images are showing up in the right place except the first one. It's showing up before the first list item, "Our Story". I've tried using the pseudo element nav li:first-child:before {display:none;} but I did not get any results. Help is greatly appreciated. This issue has me perplexed and I can't seem to find a clear answer on the web. Thanks for helping out a noob! :)

Here is my CSS:

```
.banner {
background-image: url("images/navimages/topimage.jpg");
padding: 108px 200px;
}

* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

body {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #C4EDFF;
    font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #aaa;
text-align: left; 
}

nav li {
text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaa; 
background-image: url(images/navimages/small-black-heart-md.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 40;
padding-right: 40;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline;
}

li a {
color: gray;
text-decoration: none;
}

audio {
width: 640px;
}

a:hover {
color: black;
}
```

---

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
<head>
<title>The Big Day</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<body>
<header class="banner"></header>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="ourstory.html">Our Story</a></li>
<li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="details.html">Details</a></li>
<li><a href= "wishlist.html">Wish List</a></li>
<li><a href= "index.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<BR><BR><BR>

<div style=" 
padding: 60px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
height: 400px; 
width: 620px;
border: 10px double; 
text-align: left;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;">
<p>Content here...</p></div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
nav li:first-child{
    background:none;
}
```

Comment: if it sloved your problem can you please accept my ans :)